# When to use mysqldump with '--no-autocommit'? My benchmark shows slower restore

Tags: mysql, restore, mariadb, mysqldump, mariadb-10.1

I tested quick and dirty `--no-autocommit` vs. without this option on MacBook (installed with Homebrew latest MariaDB). I restored to an empty MariaDB a 4.6 GB *.sql file. The dump made without `--no-autocommit` took 5m42.072s to restore and with `--no-autocommit` it took 1 minute longer.

Other options used for dump are `--max_allowed_packet=1G --flush-logs --single-transaction --all-databases`

```
set autocommit=0;
INSERT INTO ...
UNLOCK TABLES;
commit;
```

When to use `--no-autocommit`? In what use case this option makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `autocommit=1`, each `INSERT` will be committed before moving on to the next.  There is less overhead.  But, if the server crashes, the table will be half built because some `INSERTs` will be committed; some won't.

With

```
SET autocommit=0;
INSERT...
INSERT...
...
commit;
```

it will put all the info into a redo log for the entire table.  For large tables, this is more overhead.  Even for a tiny tables (only one `INSERT`), it might be a little slower due to the extra two statements.

Comment: By default, mysqldump also uses `--extended-insert` creating one insert statement with multiple values, so that might also explain why `--no-autocommit` doesn't make much of a difference. To get multiple inserts, you need: `--skip-extended-insert`.

Comment: @DarioSeidl - and it runs about 10 times as fast when loading.